# Identifying subsets of values significant to the total sum

Tags: decision-trees

Imagine a set of products in a store, with all the different attributes assigned to them - some of these hierarchical (e.g. categories), and some not (e.g. brand), but none of them continuous (if that is even important here). For each product, we know how much (in money-value) we've sold last year, and how much we sold this year. The sum of all of the differences in these sales is equal to the difference in total sales between the two years.

What we're interested in is finding some "nice" rules which describe the biggest sales-change-driving sets of products. For example: "Smartphones have dropped in sales by 10% (\$123456)", "Apple products increased in sales by 20% (\$31234)", etc. In other words, an end user is interested in learning "what's driving our sales up and down" in some easily consumable format. Hierarchical attributes should be taken into account here, as well as the combination of "orthogonal" attributes.

My question is not about forming those "sentences", but in general about how to find those structured "rules". Additionally, how to best identify composite rules, like "Smartphones are dropping in sales, apart from Apple smartphones which are growing".

A very important additional question is how to balance relative and absolute change of these rules. Are there some best-practice approaches on how to deal with this tradeoff?

A somewhat naive approach would be to build a decision tree for sales-change prediction (either relative or absolute) for each product, and then use that tree as a foundation for rules, or maybe just "plot" the tree itself and present to the end user.

All ideas, even ones very remote to the main question, are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I think ML is not needed here, as it is an SQL (or at least pandas) exercise. Namely, you have change in sales for each of the lowest level labels. You also have hierarchical relationship between labels Smartphones -> Apple Smartphones -> iPhone 2. So you basically need to aggregate from lower to higher label levels and look at some higher label levels you care about. Sort them from low to high by the amount you worked out, and those are your rules. There might be some rare, but expensive stuff, so might be worth weighting it by number of sales|valume|other important metric, but that is about it.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you're aiming at, but this seems to become quite convoluted when there are multiple (especially hierarchical) attributes at play. At each step, you'd need to decide which attribute you're going to group on next (to go one level up in the granularity), and it doesn't seem straightforward to me how you would pick that attribute to end up with "optimal" rules (and I fully understand that "optimal" here is not defined at all - this whole post is quite open-ended).

Comment: In terms of computational efficiency, I guess it depends on the hierarchy of labels. But a simple brute-force method, where you first unravel the hierarchy into one-to-one connections and remove duplicates: Smartphones -> Apple Smartphones -> iPhone 2 becomes  Smartphones -> iPhone 2 and Apple Smartphones -> iPhone 2. Dealing with double counting will depend on your business problem. After you got all connections, aggregation is simply looping through all lowest level items (iPhone 2) and adding their values to the higher level buckets (Smartphones, Apple Smartphones).